# Help with my H-bridge circuit using MOSFET

Tags: h-bridge, mosfet-driver

I had a problem with making H-bridge to drive 32V 6A Motor
[image: H-Bridge Circuit Schematic]

voltage control is 12V

input: IN1/IN2

whenever i tried to test it the Amp goes up in the 32V motor power "it becomes short circuit"

if you need more information let me know thanks.

Comment: Are you PWM controlling it or just on/off? What PWM frequency? Where are the datasheets for your FETs? What is the starting current or stall current for your motor? Are the PSU and FETs rated to deliver that current?

Comment: Also the 9630 looks woefully under-rated for this app. How are you heatsinking the poor little thing?

Comment: Thanks for the replay,
the controlling is On/Off not PWM
[link datasheet 1](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91291/91291.pdf)
[link datasheet 2](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91084/sihf9630.pdf)

the MAX Current for the Motor is 5.8A
yes the FETs rated to deliver more than that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really very simple. You have connected your p-type MOSFETs backwards.

Do you see the diode symbol which is part of the FET? Notice how it points downwards? There is in fact an effective diode, called a body diode, which results from the construction of the FET, and it behaves just like any other diode. As you have connected it, current will always flow through the diode, and the FET will behave as if it is always on.

Reverse the source and drain on the two IRF9630s, and try again.

Also, for what it's worth, you do not need Darlingtons as gate drivers for the p-types. Regular old NPN BJTs will work just fine.

However, at 32 volt power supply, you really should switch the 5k and 10k resistors on the p-type gates. In theory, these will provide 20 volt gate drive, and the FETs have a maximum gate drive of 20 volts. This means that you have no margin, and risk overdriving your gates. Replace the 5k with a 10k. This will give you a nominal 16 volt gate drive, which will be entirely adequate and does not flirt with disaster.

Comment: Thanks a lot i missed that i did what you told me and it did work just fine>
about the NPN BJTs i'm using it to control the H-Bridge with 5V
I reverse the source and drain on the two IRF9630
and I change the 5K resistor to 10K